# How can i restrict duplicate job creation using spring boot and spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I created a Spring Boot with Spring Batch Application and Scheduling. When i create only one job, things are working fine . But when i try to create another job using the modular approach. The jobs and it's step are running many times and they are getting duplicated.

**Getting the below error.**

```
2017-08-24 16:05:00.581  INFO 16172 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importDeptJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{JobID1=1503579900035}] and the following status: [FAILED]
2017-08-24 16:05:00.581 ERROR 16172 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : JobRepository failure forcing rollback

org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (3), where current version is 1
```

Can anyone Please guide me how to resolve these issues and run the jobs in a parallel way independent of each other ?

***Below are the configuration Classes :*** ModularJobConfiguration.java , DeptBatchConfiguration.java ,CityBatchConfiguration.java and BatchScheduler.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)
public class ModularJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory firstJob() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(DeptBatchConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory secondJob() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(CityBatchConfiguration.class);
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class DeptBatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeptBatchConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JobExecutionListener listener;

    public ItemReader<DepartmentModelReader> deptReaderSO;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceReader")
    private DataSource dataSourceReader;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceWriter")
    private DataSource dataSourceWriter;



    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void performFirstJob() throws Exception {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Job1 Started at :" + new Date());
        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID1",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = (JobExecution) jobLauncher.run(importDeptJob(jobBuilderFactory,stepdept(deptReaderSO,customWriter()),listener), param);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Job1 finished at " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000  + " seconds with status :" + execution.getExitStatus());
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<DepartmentModelReader> deptReaderSO() {
        //LOGGER.info("Inside deptReaderSO Method");
        JdbcCursorItemReader<DepartmentModelReader> deptReaderSO = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        //deptReaderSO.setSql("select id, firstName, lastname, random_num from reader");
        deptReaderSO.setSql("SELECT DEPT_CODE,DEPT_NAME,FULL_DEPT_NAME,CITY_CODE,CITY_NAME,CITY_TYPE_NAME,CREATED_USER_ID,CREATED_G_DATE,MODIFIED_USER_ID,MODIFIED_G_DATE,RECORD_ACTIVITY,DEPT_CLASS,DEPT_PARENT,DEPT_PARENT_NAME FROM TBL_SAMPLE_SAFTY_DEPTS");
        deptReaderSO.setDataSource(dataSourceReader);
        deptReaderSO.setRowMapper(
                (ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) -> {
                    if (!(resultSet.isAfterLast()) && !(resultSet.isBeforeFirst())) {
                        DepartmentModelReader recordSO = new DepartmentModelReader();
                        recordSO.setDeptCode(resultSet.getString("DEPT_CODE"));
                        recordSO.setDeptName(resultSet.getString("DEPT_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setFullDeptName(resultSet.getString("FULL_DEPT_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setCityCode(resultSet.getInt("CITY_CODE"));
                        recordSO.setCityName(resultSet.getString("CITY_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setCityTypeName(resultSet.getString("CITY_TYPE_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setCreatedUserId(resultSet.getInt("CREATED_USER_ID"));
                        recordSO.setCreatedGDate(resultSet.getDate("CREATED_G_DATE"));
                        recordSO.setModifiedUserId(resultSet.getString("MODIFIED_USER_ID"));
                        recordSO.setModifiedGDate(resultSet.getDate("MODIFIED_G_DATE"));
                        recordSO.setRecordActivity(resultSet.getInt("RECORD_ACTIVITY"));
                        recordSO.setDeptClass(resultSet.getInt("DEPT_CLASS"));
                        recordSO.setDeptParent(resultSet.getString("DEPT_PARENT"));
                        recordSO.setDeptParentName(resultSet.getString("DEPT_PARENT_NAME"));

                       // LOGGER.info("RowMapper record : {}", recordSO.getDeptCode() +" | "+recordSO.getDeptName());
                        return recordSO;
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Returning null from rowMapper");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
        return deptReaderSO;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<DepartmentModelReader, DepartmentModelWriter> processor() {
        //LOGGER.info("Inside Processor Method");
        return new RecordProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<DepartmentModelWriter> customWriter(){
        //LOGGER.info("Inside customWriter Method");
        return new CustomItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importDeptJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step stepdept,JobExecutionListener listener){
        return jobs.get("importDeptJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(stepdept).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepdept(ItemReader<DepartmentModelReader> deptReaderSO,
            ItemWriter<DepartmentModelWriter> writerSO) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside stepdept Method");

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepdept").<DepartmentModelReader, DepartmentModelWriter>chunk(5)
                .reader(deptReaderSO).processor(processor()).writer(customWriter()).transactionManager(platformTransactionManager(dataSourceWriter)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchWriteService batchWriteService() {
        return new BatchWriteService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSourceWriter") DataSource dataSourceWriter) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceWriter);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class CityBatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CityBatchConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JobExecutionListener listener;

    public ItemReader<CitiesModelReader> citiesReaderSO;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceReader")
    private DataSource dataSourceReader;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceWriter")
    private DataSource dataSourceWriter;


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void performSecondJob() throws Exception {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("\n Job2 Started at :" + new Date());

        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID2",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = (JobExecution) jobLauncher.run(importCitiesJob(jobBuilderFactory,stepcity(citiesReaderSO,customCitiesWriter()),listener), param);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Job2 finished at " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000  + " seconds with status :" + execution.getExitStatus());
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemReader<CitiesModelReader> citiesReaderSO() {
        //LOGGER.info("Inside readerSO Method");
        JdbcCursorItemReader<CitiesModelReader> readerSO = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        readerSO.setSql("SELECT CITY_CODE,CITY_NAME,PARENT_CITY,CITY_TYPE,CITY_TYPE_NAME,CREATED_G_DATE,CREATED_USER_ID,MODIFIED_G_DATE,MODIFIED_USER_ID,RECORD_ACTIVITY FROM TBL_SAMPLE_SAFTY_CITIES");
        readerSO.setDataSource(dataSourceReader);
        readerSO.setRowMapper(
                (ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) -> {
                    if (!(resultSet.isAfterLast()) && !(resultSet.isBeforeFirst())) {
                        CitiesModelReader recordSO = new CitiesModelReader();
                        recordSO.setCityCode(resultSet.getLong("CITY_CODE"));
                        recordSO.setCityName(resultSet.getString("CITY_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setParentCity(resultSet.getInt("PARENT_CITY"));
                        recordSO.setCityType(resultSet.getString("CITY_TYPE"));
                        recordSO.setCityTypeName(resultSet.getString("CITY_TYPE_NAME"));
                        recordSO.setCreatedGDate(resultSet.getDate("CREATED_G_DATE"));
                        recordSO.setCreatedUserId(resultSet.getString("CREATED_USER_ID"));
                        recordSO.setModifiedGDate(resultSet.getDate("MODIFIED_G_DATE"));
                        recordSO.setModifiedUserId(resultSet.getString("MODIFIED_USER_ID"));
                        recordSO.setRecordActivity(resultSet.getInt("RECORD_ACTIVITY"));

                        //LOGGER.info("RowMapper record : {}", recordSO.toString());
                        return recordSO;
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.info("Returning null from rowMapper");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
        return readerSO;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<CitiesModelReader,CitiesModelWriter> citiesProcessor() {
        //LOGGER.info("Inside Processor Method");
        return new RecordCitiesProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<CitiesModelWriter> customCitiesWriter(){
        LOGGER.info("Inside customCitiesWriter Method");
        return new CustomCitiesWriter();
    }           

    @Bean
    public Job importCitiesJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step stepcity,JobExecutionListener listener) {

        LOGGER.info("Inside importCitiesJob Method");
        return jobs.get("importCitiesJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(stepcity).end().build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step stepcity(ItemReader<CitiesModelReader> readerSO,
            ItemWriter<CitiesModelWriter> writerSO) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside stepCity Method");

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepcity").<CitiesModelReader, CitiesModelWriter>chunk(5)
                .reader(readerSO).processor(citiesProcessor()).writer(customCitiesWriter()).transactionManager(platformTransactionManager(dataSourceWriter)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchWriteService batchWriteService() {
        return new BatchWriteService();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSourceWriter") DataSource dataSourceWriter) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceWriter);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}





@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchScheduler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchScheduler.class);

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
            ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("Inside mapJobRepositoryFactory method");

        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new 
                MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);

        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("Inside jobRepository method");

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {

        LOGGER.info("Inside jobLauncher method");

        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        launcher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
        return launcher;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **map-based** `SimpleJobRepository` created from [`MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) is **not thread-safe**.

From the Javadocs:

> A FactoryBean that automates the creation of a SimpleJobRepository using non-persistent in-memory DAO implementations. This repository is **only really intended for use in testing and rapid prototyping**. In such settings you might find that ResourcelessTransactionManager is useful (as long as your business logic does not use a relational database). **Not suited for use in multi-threaded jobs** with splits, although it should be safe to use in a multi-threaded step.

You can create a JDBC-based `SimpleJobRepository` from [`JobRepositoryFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html), which may utilize an in-memory [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database if you don't require that [Batch metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) be persisted.

Since you are using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), **to use an H2-backed `JobRepository`** simply remove your `JobRepository` bean and add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot will [automatically configure a `DataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration) as though you had configured the following in your `application.properties` file and [automatically use that `DataSource` in the creation of a `JobRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/index-single.html#javaConfig).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

**Alternatively, to use some other JDBC-backed `JobRepository`** add the JDBC dependencies for your RDBMS of choice to your project, and configure a `DataSource` for it (either in code as a `DataSource` bean, or [in `application.properties` using the `spring.datasource` prefix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) as shown above).  Spring Boot will [automatically use this `DataSource` during the creation of the `JobRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/index-single.html#configuringJobRepository) bean.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your valuable time to respond !